# How to download audio(mp3) files from internet and them store in an iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, audio, download, mp3

I tried to download audio (mp3) files from my online server and store them in "Documents" folder of my iPhone app so that i can play them in my app without any internet connection. 
I used the following code to download and store it.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]]    
                                   queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
    completionHandler: ^( NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error ) {
          if(error)
          { }
           else
          {
             NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
             [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
          }
     }];
```

By this code, i can download the mp3 files and it is in data variable, but it seems [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; is not working. 
It is not saving in Documents.
For image file, it worked with following code.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

So for mp3 file, is there any way similar with image file save?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
 NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:soundURL];
```

You can put it to background queue if you want async.

I hope so it will help

Answer (score -1):

Take care of existing the file with the same path you are trying to write. You must have any file with the same name (**filePath**). In this case **writeToFile** method will work properly.